# Squarespace form, control email subject

Tags: squarespace

I have a squarespace page, with a form used for intake of new clients. By default the form has a "Subject" box, which becomes the subject for the email. The issue is when two visitors submit the form with the same subject (seems unlikely but it happens), then Gmail treats them as related emails and forms a conversations.

So I am trying to gain control of this subject line. It can be anything at all, as long as it's unique.

My concern is it seems like my only option it to move the entire website into developer mode, where it will no longer get security updates and such, just to tweak a form submission to add a time stamp or something of that nature.

I am looking for a time efficient solution, I could build a website for it, but I am in search of a quick fix at the moment.

Form link: https://www.transformationcounselling.com/contact

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing with the email?

Comment: Updated. Form is for new client providing information so we can best serve them.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: Not so much. Turning off Gmail conversations works but at a high cost. I found the best solution was to integrate a JotForm instead of using the built-in Squarespace form.

Answer (score -1):

Is Conversation View enabled on your Gmail account? Disabling it can help separate multiple Squarespace form submissions turning into conversations. This Google support guide can help: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en